# Update reference to cell in another document through version updates

Tags: vba, excel

Lets say there's an Excel document `C:\Budget-v034-2012.xlsx` (doc A) and another Excel document (doc B) that references a cell in the first document like this: `='C:\[Budget-v034-2012.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1`

When doc A is updated, it is saved with an updated version number (i.e. v034 becomes v035). How can I make doc B automatically update its reference with the new version number?

The solution doesn't need to be completely automatic. There could, for instance, be a cell in doc B where the current version number is supplied manually, and all references incorporate the supplied number automatically. How could such incorporation be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple (simplistic?) solution:

In your document B, you can store the path and/or the name of the file (let say in cell A1 in my example) and use the [`INDIRECT`](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm) formula to give you the result in the other cell.

- in cell A1: `Budget-v034-2012.xlsx`
- in the other cell : `=INDIRECT('C:[' & A1 & ']Sheet1'!$A$1)`

---

For better maintainability, note that you can also use [Named Range](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/named.htm).

- Add the path or the name in a cell of a sheet of your doc B (Sheet1, cell A1 or whatever)
- Enter a name (the one you want) on the top left (above cell A1), let say `Path`
- On the other sheet, you can use this formula: `=INDIRECT('C:[' & Path & ']Sheet1'!$A$1)`

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are good reasons, it is often easier to keep the same filename and update the version details in a cell in the file. That way any external links will be kept up to date with the relevant data.

If you save the new file with a new filename from within Excel, the links in the other workbook will still link to the old file and will only become broken if you delete the file or rename it externally.

There are several ways to do this manually in Excel

1. In Excel Data/Edit Links/highlight the source and click change source
2. Using Find & Replace, eg find [Budget-v034-2012.xlsx] replace with [Budget-v035-2012.xlsx] (Make sure options are enabled and Lookin:= formulas and March Entire cell contents:= FALSE)

If you record the macros doing both of the above you will get something similar to

```
Sub Macro1()

ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="C:\Users\ooo\Desktop\Budget-v034-2012.xlsx", NewName _
        :="C:\Users\ooo\Desktop\Budget-v035-2012.xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks

End sub

Sub Macro1()

    Cells.Replace What:="[Budget-v034-2012.xlsx]", Replacement:="[Budget-v035-2012.xlsx]", LookAt:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```